# Using a For Loop to create and add data to dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, dictionary

Trying to create a dictionary with rep:unencrypted_pdf key, value pairs.  Attempting the dictionary comprehension approach but it's giving me a syntax error at "for".  How can I correct this?

```
file_dict = {
    for report in os.listdir(PATH):
        split = re.split("[_.]", unencrypted_pdf)
        rep = split[1]
        file_dict[rep] = unencrypted_pdf
}
```

Comment: Uhhh. `file_dict = {}` will initialize the dictionary, then you'll be able to add values to it. The current syntax is wrong, you can't put a `for` loop *and* assigments in curly brackets.

Comment: thank you @vaultah I am reworking some code and misread the suggestion apparently.  That fixed my issue.

Comment: This question was closed while I was trying to explain that, if you want to use [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), the syntax is different!!

Comment: @memoselyk So I should be able to use a for loop to initialize and add data to the dictionary?

Comment: @AlliDeacon, If your intilialization code fits in a single expression, you can use dictionary comprehension to do it in a single shot, like `file_dict = {re.split("[_.]", report)[1] : report for for report in os.listdir(PATH)}` but if your expression grows too complex to be understanable, use the approach mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first initialize a dictionary, and then after that line you can assign values to it. Like below:

```
file_dict = {}
for report in os.listdir(PATH):
    splitted = re.split("[_.]", unencrypted_pdf)
    rep = splitted[1]
    file_dict[rep] = unencrypted_pdf
```